# How to hide all the ribbons except the workflow one in experience editor

Tags: experience-editor, workflow

I have a requirement of hiding all the ribbons except workflow ribbon so that content approver concentrates on only workflow .how do i achieve this ?what is the right way of hiding this ? our sitecore version is 8.1.[image]

Comment: Do you have a special role for content approvers? I would maybe try to remove permissions for rest of the ribbons in core db for that role

Comment: Do you still need the Experience Editor after all? Why not simply use the Workbox?

Comment: thats the req they wanted to see the whole page prview there and approve